# MySQL get minimum from function

Tags: mysql, database

I want to get the minimum from a "dynamic" value determined by a function `DISTANCE_BETWEEN`.

```
SELECT d.id 
FROM (SELECT id , DISTANCE_BETWEEN (Latitude,Longitude,43.2560997009,-2.9078400135) AS distance FROM Locations) AS D 
WHERE MIN(d.distance);
```

Can't get it right

```
Invalid use of group function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way using `order by`

```
SELECT D.id 
FROM (SELECT id , DISTANCE_BETWEEN (Latitude,Longitude,43.2560997009,-2.9078400135) AS distance FROM Locations) AS D
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Both answers work, but this one seems simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id
FROM Locations
WHERE DISTANCE_BETWEEN (Latitude,Longitude,43.2560997009,-2.9078400135) =
    (SELECT MIN(DISTANCE_BETWEEN (Latitude,Longitude,43.2560997009,-2.9078400135)) FROM Locations)
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is just to move the function to the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT D.id 
FROM locations
ORDER BY DISTANCE_BETWEEN(Latitude, Longitude, 43.2560997009, -2.9078400135)
LIMIT 1;
```

This is the simplest method for expressing the logic (under some circumstances, it might not be the most efficient).

Comment: Why should it not be efficient?

Comment: @ElDude . . . This may calculate the distance multiple times for a given row.  If the subquery is materialized, then the distance is only calculated once.